# Android application run multiple times when install from android studio

Tags: android, manifest

i have an android application and when i use a flavor that put this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />         

    <uses-permission android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- //ALP 12.SEP.13  - INICIO -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- //ALP 12.SEP.13  - FIN -->

    <permission
        android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- //ALP 12.SEP.13 - INICIO  Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <!-- //ALP 12.SEP.13 - FIN -->

    <application
        android:name="sisa.android.finder.RootApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/clink_mobile"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">


        <!-- URL SERVER PRODUCCION ACSA -->

            <meta-data
            android:name="server"
            android:value="fish.aguasdecorrientes.com:9595"
            tools:replace="android:value"/>


        <!-- URL SERVER DESARROLLO / TESTING ACSA -->
        <!--
            <meta-data
            android:name="server"
            android:value="acsa.sisa.com.ar" />
         -->

        <!-- KEY SERVER PRODUCCION GCM ACSA -->
         <meta-data
            android:name="sender_c2dm"
            android:value="\ 693792848545"
            tools:replace="android:value"/>

        <!-- KEY SERVER PRODUCCION MAP ACSA -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyChIjhdV_UPYsujNXBE0jzzhojRVlr5YZg"
            tools:replace="android:value"/>



        <meta-data
            android:name="permite_habilitar_informar"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="aplicacion"
            android:value="FINDER_SISA" />
        <!-- 
        <activity android:name="sisa.android.finder.Route"
                  android:theme="@style/FormTheme"
                  android:icon="@drawable/wa_route_iso"
                  android:label="@string/route">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        -->
        <!-- MyTask -->
        <activity android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage" />

        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.Form"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_form_iso"
            android:label="@string/form"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.MapRoute"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_route_iso"
            android:label="@string/route"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.Destino"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_route_iso"
            android:label="@string/info_destino"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.EstadoFinder"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_form_iso"
            android:label="@string/informacion"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.form.Utilidades.Firma"
            android:theme="@style/FormThemeDialog" >
        </activity>


        <!-- WhereAre -->
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.Finder"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_iso"
            android:label="@string/where_are"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:replace="android:label"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.EditarGrupo"
            android:label="@string/nuevo_grupo"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.EditarUsuario"
            android:label="@string/invitar_usuario"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.Acerca"
            android:label="@string/acerca"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.DetalleGrupo"
            android:label="@string/info_grupo"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.Encontrar"
            android:label="@string/encontrar_grupo"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme">
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="sisa.android.alive.C2DMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Receive the registration id -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="sisa.android.alive.NetworkStatusReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.IngresarSISA"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_form_iso"
            android:label="@string/ingresar"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="sisa.android.finder.FinderReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.alive.INIT" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.alive.STOP" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.alive.INIT_RESET" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.alive.STOP_RESET" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.alive.intent.TICK" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.alive.intent.NETWORK_AVAILABLE" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.alive.intent.CONEXION_CHANGE" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderDesarr" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.EditarForm"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_form_iso"
            android:label="@string/form"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.MapForm"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_form_iso"
            android:label="@string/form"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="sisa.android.finder.VerMyTask"
            android:icon="@drawable/wa_form_iso"
            android:label="@string/form"
            android:theme="@style/FormTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sisa.finder.mytask" />

                <category android:name="sisa.android.finderAcsa" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>``

</manifest>
```

the application run three times when I'm install it from the android studio, even if I use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` or `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`, I know that the app run three times because I put a log in the `onCreate` of one of the launchers.

Comment: please share you start activity code